# pymc3 improving theano compile time before sampling

Tags: pymc, theano

I'm working with this hierarchical Bayesian model:

```python
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd
import theano.tensor as T

categories = pd.Categorical(df.cat)
n_categories = len(set(categories.codes))
cat_idx = categories.codes

with pm.Model()
    mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_a', 0, sd=100**2)
    sig_a = pm.Uniform('sig_a', lower=0, upper=100)
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=mu_a, sd=sig_a, shape=n_categories)

    betas = []
    for f in FEATURE_LIST:
        mu_b = pm.Normal('mu_b_%s' % f, 0, sd=100**2)
        sig_b = pm.Uniform('sig_b_%s' % f, lower=0, upper=100)
        betas.append(pm.Normal('beta_%s' % f, mu=mu_b, sd=sig_b, shape=n_categories))


    logit = 1.0 / (1.0 + T.exp(-(
                sum([betas[i][cat_idx] * X_train[f].values for i, f in enumerate(FEATURE_LIST)]) 
                + alpha[cat_idx]
            )))

    y_est = pm.Bernoulli('y_est', logit, observed=df.y)

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    trace = pm.sample(2000, pm.NUTS(), start=start, random_seed=42, njobs=40)
```

I would imagine that replace my python list of priors and individual additions and multiplications with proper Theano code (perhaps using `T.dot`?) would improve the performance of the call to sample.  How do I set this up in Theano correctly?  I imagine that I need to do something like `shape=(n_features, n_categories)` for my priors, but I'm not sure how to do the category index in the dot product.